# Simple OpenCL program not working

Tags: parallel-processing, opencl, gpu

This program is a simple parallel program which adds the elements of 2 vectors. 
The program was error free and it was compiled successfully but the results are not right

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream> 
#include <iomanip>
#include <array>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <OpenCL/opencl.h>
#else
#include <CL/cl.h>
#include <time.h>
#endif



#define MAX_SOURCE_SIZE (0x100000)

// number of points in Both  A and B files (number of rows)
const int number_of_points = 11; 
// number of points axis in Both  A and B files (number of Columns)
const int number_of_axis = 3;       

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    clock_t tStart = clock();
    // Create the two input vectors
    // working variables
    int i;
    ifstream input_fileA, input_fileB;  // input files
    string line;    // transfer row from file to array
    float x;        // transfer word from file to array
    int row = 0;    // number of rows of file A,B (= array)
    int col = 0;    // number of rows of file A,B (= array)

    // working arrays
    // array contains file A data
    float arrayA[number_of_points][number_of_axis]={{0}};
    // array contains file B data
    float arrayB[number_of_points][number_of_axis]={{0}};


//  float X1[number_of_points]; // X values of file A points
    float Y1[number_of_points]; // Y values of file A points
//  float X2[number_of_points]; // X values of file B points
    float Y2[number_of_points]; // Y values of file B points
    float *X1 = (float*)malloc(sizeof(float)*number_of_points);
    float *X2 = (float*)malloc(sizeof(float)*number_of_points);

    // import input files
    input_fileA.open(argv[1]);
    input_fileB.open(argv[2]);  

    // transfer input files data to array
    // input file A to arrayA
    row = 0;
    while (getline(input_fileA, line))
    {

        istringstream streamA(line);
        col = 0;
        while(streamA >> x){
            arrayA[row][col] = x;
            col++;
        }
        row++;
    }
    // input file B to arrayB
    row = 0;
    while (getline(input_fileB, line))
    {

        istringstream streamB(line);
        col = 0;
        while(streamB >> x){
            arrayB[row][col] = x;
            col++;
        }
        row++;
    }

    // put Xs of points in X vectors and Ys of points in Y vectors
    // input file A
    for (int i = 0; i<number_of_points; i++){
        X1[i] = arrayA[i][1];
        Y1[i] = arrayA[i][2];
    }

    // input file B
    for (int i = 0; i<number_of_points; i++){
        X2[i] = arrayB[i][1];
        Y2[i] = arrayB[i][2];
    }       

//    int i;
//    const int LIST_SIZE = 50;
//    int *A = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*number_of_points);
//    int *B = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*number_of_points);
//    for(i = 0; i < number_of_points; i++) {
//        A[i] = X1[i];
//        B[i] = X2[i];
//    }

    // Load the kernel source code into the array source_str
    FILE *fp;
    char *source_str;
    size_t source_size;

    fp = fopen("vector_add_kernel.cl", "r");
    if (!fp) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to load kernel.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    source_str = (char*)malloc(MAX_SOURCE_SIZE);
    source_size = fread( source_str, 1, MAX_SOURCE_SIZE, fp);
    fclose( fp );

    // Get platform and device information
    cl_platform_id platform_id = NULL;
    cl_device_id device_id = NULL;   
    cl_uint ret_num_devices;
    cl_uint ret_num_platforms;
    cl_int ret = clGetPlatformIDs(1, &platform_id, &ret_num_platforms);
    ret = clGetDeviceIDs( platform_id, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, 1, 
            &device_id, &ret_num_devices);

    // Create an OpenCL context
    cl_context context =
        clCreateContext( NULL, 1, &device_id, NULL, NULL, &ret);

    // Create a command queue
    cl_command_queue command_queue = 
        clCreateCommandQueue(context, device_id, 0, &ret);

    // Create memory buffers on the device for each vector 
    cl_mem x1_mem_obj = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, 
            number_of_points * sizeof(float), NULL, &ret);
    cl_mem x2_mem_obj = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY,
            number_of_points * sizeof(float), NULL, &ret);
    cl_mem c_mem_obj = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, 
            number_of_points * sizeof(float), NULL, &ret);

    // Copy the lists A and B to their respective memory buffers
    ret = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(command_queue, x1_mem_obj, CL_TRUE, 0,
            number_of_points * sizeof(float), X1, 0, NULL, NULL);
    ret = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(command_queue, x2_mem_obj, CL_TRUE, 0, 
            number_of_points * sizeof(float), X2, 0, NULL, NULL);

    // Create a program from the kernel source
    cl_program program = clCreateProgramWithSource(context, 1, 
         (const char **)&source_str, (const size_t *)&source_size, &ret);

    // Build the program
    ret = clBuildProgram(program, 1, &device_id, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    // Create the OpenCL kernel
    cl_kernel kernel = clCreateKernel(program, "vector_add", &ret);

    // Set the arguments of the kernel
    ret = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&x1_mem_obj);
    ret = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&x2_mem_obj);
    ret = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 2, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&c_mem_obj);

    // Execute the OpenCL kernel on the list
    size_t global_item_size = number_of_points; // Process the entire lists
    size_t local_item_size = 64; // Process in groups of 64
    ret = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command_queue, kernel, 1, NULL, 
            &global_item_size, &local_item_size, 0, NULL, NULL);

    // Read the memory buffer C on the device to the local variable C
//    int *C = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*number_of_points);
    float *C = (float*)malloc(sizeof(float)*number_of_points);
    ret = clEnqueueReadBuffer(command_queue, c_mem_obj, CL_TRUE, 0, 
            number_of_points * sizeof(float), C, 0, NULL, NULL);

    // Display the result to the screen
    for(i = 0; i < number_of_points; i++)
        printf("%f + %f = %f\n", X1[i], X2[i], C[i]);

    // Clean up
    ret = clFlush(command_queue);
    ret = clFinish(command_queue);
    ret = clReleaseKernel(kernel);
    ret = clReleaseProgram(program);
    ret = clReleaseMemObject(x1_mem_obj);
    ret = clReleaseMemObject(x2_mem_obj);
    ret = clReleaseMemObject(c_mem_obj);
    ret = clReleaseCommandQueue(command_queue);
    ret = clReleaseContext(context);
    free(X1);
    free(X2);
    free(C);

printf("ALL Time taken: %.2fs\n", (double)(clock() - tStart)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    return 0;
}
```

and the kernel file

```
__kernel void vector_add(__global float *X1,
                         __global float *X2,
                         __global float *C) {

    // Get the index of the current element
    int i = get_global_id(0);

    // Do the operation
    C[i] = X1[i] + X2[i];

}
```

The result was

```
0.000000 + 0.000000 = 0.000000
1.000000 + 1.000000 = 0.000000
2.000000 + 2.000000 = 0.000000
3.000000 + 3.000000 = 0.000000
4.000000 + 4.000000 = 0.000000
5.000000 + 5.000000 = 0.000000
6.000000 + 6.000000 = 0.000000
7.000000 + 7.000000 = 0.000000
8.000000 + 8.000000 = 0.000000
9.000000 + 9.000000 = 0.000000
1.000000 + 1.000000 = 0.000000
ALL Time taken: 0.07s
```

Comment: There is a viable piece of information missing, namely: What output did you expect? It's somewhat impossible to answer your question in it's current state. Please [edit] that information into your question. Thanks!

Comment: thanks but @jprice answered and it works now,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've committed one of the cardinal sins of OpenCL programming, in that you are not checking the error codes from any of your OpenCL API calls! You should *always* check the return code from *every single* OpenCL API call. If you did this, it would point you towards the problem very quickly.

The problem is in your kernel enqueue call. If you check the error code, you'll see that you are getting `-54` back, which corresponds to `CL_INVALID_WORK_GROUP_SIZE`. Specifically, kernel invocations have the requirement that the work-group size (local size) *exactly* divides the global size. You are asking for a work-group size of 64 and a global size of 11, which does not fulfil this requirement.

You can also pass `NULL` as the work-group size parameter, and the OpenCL implementation will pick a work-group size that will definitely work on your behalf.

Comment: you are right, it works now, I am new in opencl how can I check this?

Comment: You've assigned the error return value to "ret" then you simply ignore it. Printing it out would be a start, it should be CL_SUCCESS if there is no error.